# Checkout error - No such entity with cartid

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3

when we make check out get the below error  Can you please advise me
**no such entity with cartid magento 2.3.2**

[image: issue image]

Comment: update question with more data from exception.log.

Comment: please provide me with path for this file

Comment: `/root/var/log/` you'll see all log files.

Comment: Please check the network tab from Inspect and show a screenshot here for more details where you got error.